# Why is my 3d object clamp not working in unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, screen

**Summary:** I'm trying out stuff in unity to better understand it.I created a 3d object with a rigidbody and froze the y axis. I placed to camera to look downwards towards the 3d object where the object can move left, right and up,down using the x and z axis.

**Problem:** The problem is the player is going out of the boundaries of the screen.

This is my code which I have based from my own understanding (in the unity manuals) and from other peoples code that had the same problem.

```
private Vector3 transformPos;

void LateUpdate () 
{
    //Defined the boundaries of the screen by using ViewPortToWorldPoint. I tried ViewportToWorldPoint as well and it did not work
    float left = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(Vector3.zero).x;
    float right = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(Vector3.one).x;
    float top = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(Vector3.zero).y;
    float bottom = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(Vector3.one).y;

    //Brought the player transform from World units to screen unit. Where x is x, z from the 3d object acts as y, and y is z.
    transformPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint (transform.position);
    //This debug was to check if z is y in the ViewportPoint and it was
    Debug.Log(transformPos);

    float x = transformPos.x;
    //Calling it z because I dont wanna confuse myself when I convert it back
    float z = transformPos.y;
    
    //This is where I start the clamping using if statements
    if(transformPos.x <= left)
    {
        x = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.x, 0.1f,0.9f);
    }
    else if(transformPos.x >= right)
    {
        x = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.x, 0.1f,0.9f);
    }

    if(transformPos.y <= top)
    {
        z = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.y, 0.1f,0.9f);
    }
    else if( transformPos.y >= bottom)
    {
        z = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.y, 0.1f,0.9f);
    }

    //And then finally I convert it back to world unit where the values is just placed in. x is x, y of the 3d object remains the same, and z 
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x,transform.position.y,z));
    
}
```

The picture below is what I got from this code:

[image]

As you can see from my main camera down right, it is completely outside the bounds of my screen and I cannot move it. So there is obviously something wrong with my code, but yet I don't understand where I am wrong.

### Edit #1

The cube in the picture is the one I am using as my player

### Edit #2

The code below is the player movement script I've attached on my player along with the above script. I don't think it is conflicting with it but just in case. The movement also has a bit of a problem (I'm trying to move the player using the phone tilt function), but I'm trying to fix it as well

```
  Rigidbody playerRigidbody;

public float speed = 10;
private Vector3 movement;
private Vector3 tilt ;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    tilt = Input.acceleration.normalized;
    tilt = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0, 0) * tilt;
    //movement = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.normalized.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    //  horizontal movement code through device rotation
    //var movement = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.normalized.x, 0.0f, Input.acceleration.normalized.z);
    //playerRigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;
    MoveCharacter(tilt);

}

private void MoveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
{
    //playerRigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Comment: What object had attached this script?

Comment: The cube in the picture, Im using that as my player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Vector3 transformPos;

void LateUpdate()
{
    //Defined the boundaries of the screen by using ViewPortToWorldPoint. I tried ViewportToWorldPoint as well and it did not work
    float LeftBottom = 1;
    float RightBottom = 0;
    float LeftTop = 1;
    float RightTop = 0;
    Debug.Log($"Left: {LeftBottom} \n Right: {RightBottom} \n Top: {LeftTop} \n Bottom: {RightTop}");
    //Brought the player transform from World units to screen unit. Where x is x, z from the 3d object acts as y, and y is z.
    transformPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
    //This debug was to check if z is y in the ViewportPoint and it was
    Debug.Log(transformPos);

    float x = transformPos.x;
    //Calling it z because I dont wanna confuse myself when I convert it back
    float z = transformPos.y;

    //This is where I start the clamping using if statements
    if (transformPos.x <= LeftBottom)
    {
        x = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.x, 0.1f, 0.9f);
        Debug.Log(x);
    }
    else if (transformPos.x >= RightBottom)
    {
        x = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.x, 0.1f, 0.9f);
    }

    if (transformPos.y <= LeftTop)
    {
        z = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.y, 0.1f, 0.9f);
    }
    else if (transformPos.y >= RightTop)
    {
        z = Mathf.Clamp(transformPos.y, 0.1f, 0.9f);
    }

    //And then finally I convert it back to world unit where the values is just placed in. x is x, y of the 3d object remains the same, and z 
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x, z, 1));

}
```

Comment: It sometimes works then it doesnt, it just gets stuck and then the cube will stutter for some reason

Comment: I checked several times and realised that the script that was making my cube stuck and stutter is the movement script, but I dont understand what is making it that way

Answer (score -1):

The above code works. Thank you @Ubaldo Vitiello. The reason Im adding my own answer here as well is to explain why the player will move for a bit before coming to a complete stop and then stutter. Took me a while but I finally understood the reason.
This is because "WorldToViewportPoint" is incompatible with "rigidbody.MovePosition". Now this is just from my understanding so I could be wrong, but MovePosition is where the player's rigidbody is moved to the position that you specify. The position only occurs in **World space**. "WorldToViewportPoint" transforms **world space into viewport space**.This is why my player moved for a bit before completing to a dead stop because my second script attached to the player is converting it to viewport space. Now the reason why my player will then stutter is because I was then transforming the viewport space back to world space. These two codes are simply incompatible with each other, that is all.
How I resolved it was using rigidbody.velocity